# Как загрузить xml из ресурсов для Jsoup

Tags: java, android, xml

```
Document d = Jsoup.parse(R.xml.document);
```

Как это можно сделать? Метод `parse()` принимает `String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
String html = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"><tests><test><id>xxx</id><status>xxx</status></test><test><id>xxx</id><status>xxx</status></test></tests></xml>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
for (Element e : doc.select("test")) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

[Отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9947639/5330439)

Comment: Спасибо.положил xml файлы в assets и от туда достал по InputStream.

Comment: @maks_007, raw ресурсы удобнее.